Does GUI layouting always have exponential complexity?
I am designing a simple GUI "framework" with widgets and layouts. Let's illustrate the problem on the simple example of a basic horizontal layout, which places its child widgets next to each other and if there is any space left at the end, it will leave it empty. Vertically, they will all be stretched to the full height of the layout.
From this, it is clear that the dimensions of a widget are not fully known ahead of time. The horizontal layout asks each child to take the minimum possible space horizontally. On the other hand, the dimensions of the root layout (which fills the app window) are known, so if the horizontal layout was the root layout, we would know the height of each child.
Therefore, I came up with the following interface of the layouting function:
Dimensions layout(Dimensions minDimensions, Dimensions maxDimensions);

So for the first child within the horizontal layout, this would be
child->layout(Dimensions(0, parentMinDimensions.height), parentMaxDimensions);

because its width can be arbitrarily small, but no greater than that of the entire layout, and vertically, it should match the layout, so the same constraints apply.
Let's try implementing the layout function for the horizontal layout:
Dimensions layout(Dimensions minDimensions, Dimensions maxDimensions) {
    int remainingWidth = maxDimensions.width;
    for (Widget *child : children) {
        Dimensions childDimensions = child->layout(
            Dimensions(0,              minDimensions.height),
            Dimensions(remainingWidth, maxDimensions.height)
        );
        remainingWidth -= childDimensions.width;
        minDimensions.height = max(minDimensions.height, childDimensions.height);
    }
    return Dimensions(maxDimensions.width-remainingWidth, minDimensions.height);
}

Looks good, but there is one problem. The layout was supposed to stretch all children vertically to its height, but if the horizontal layout is for example the child of a vertical layout, then the input min height and max height differ and each widget may end up with a different height instead. And this is where the problem appears. I don't believe this can be resolved without evaluating the layout of each child twice:
Dimensions layout(Dimensions minDimensions, Dimensions maxDimensions) {
    // First pass - determine height
    int height = minDimensions.height;
    int remainingWidth = maxDimensions.width;
    for (Widget *child : children) {
        Dimensions childDimensions = child->layout(
            Dimensions(0,              minDimensions.height),
            Dimensions(remainingWidth, maxDimensions.height)
        );
        remainingWidth -= childDimensions.width;
        height = max(height, childDimensions.height);
    }
    // Second pass - apply height
    remainingWidth = maxDimensions.width;
    for (Widget *child : children) {
        Dimensions childDimensions = child->layout(
            Dimensions(0,              height),
            Dimensions(remainingWidth, height)
        );
        remainingWidth -= childDimensions.width;
    }
    return Dimensions(maxDimensions.width-remainingWidth, height);
}

The layouts are organized in a tree hierarchy of arbitrary size and depth, and evaluating the entire subtree at each node more than once results in exponential complexity. There are some scenarios, where the layout needs to be quickly recomputed every frame, for example when a user is resizing the window, so that would be bad.
Since GUI frameworks with this paradigm are extremely common, I was wondering if they also have this issue, but maybe in practice the hierarchies aren't deep enough for it to be a significant problem, or if there is actually some way to guarantee better than exponential runtime even in the worst case scenario (and without sacrificing the flexibility of layouts).
Footnote
I am aware that rather than calling layout twice, I can instead have two functions like
Dimensions measure(Dimensions minDimensions, Dimensions maxDimensions);
void layout(Dimensions exactDimensions);

and maybe even guarantee that the first one only ever traverses the tree once, but in the above example, I would still have to call both in the layout function for each child, so the exponential complexity is still there. Also, I would no longer have the ability to skip the second round if min and max height were equal, so I don't believe it would even be beneficial in all cases.
I am also aware that caching intermediate results can help, but is there actually a strategy that can definitively change the worst case complexity in all possible scenarios? The "big O" exponential complexity is what I'm interested in, not constant factor optimizations.

@Detheroc, does big O really matter here? In any real GUI, how deep will the nesting of layouts be? I'm thinking that 3, 4 levels deep is already reaching the limits of what is a user-friendly GUI. Certainly not 100 levels deep. As big O is about asymptotic complexity, how does that matter for GUIs where I don't think we're interested in dealing with large depths of layouts?

@trincot Let's think of it more as a theoretical question even if it does not matter in practice. However, I'm sure I've seen usable UI layouts where I could tell the depth was way over 10.

One way all desktop GUI frameworks get around this is only allowing you to specify if the widget is only growing or shrinking , it doesn't have both a min and max size, i don't know how web browsers handle this though

The last layout engine I made wasn't using "at least" and stuff like that -- instead, every object had 4 unknowns (x, y, width, height) and the layout was just a set of linear equations to be solved. There was some "trickery" with the width and height to better handle min sizes, but other than that the only real problem was figuring out the min size for the window, which kind of required a binary search, but that would only work if y/height and x/width wasn't mixed up in equations.

Why would evaluating twice give exponential complexity if doing so once doesn’t?

The last layout engine I worked with (WPF) would often have layouts of 60-200 deep, as easily demonstrated with the Snoop WPF spy utility.  Even "simple" layouts would be 30+ deep.

@AhmedAEK • I'm not actually sure how WPF's layout system solves the push-me-pull-you problem and constraints.  It's a two pass system: measure pass, arrange pass.  (I currently work with the Express View system, and I wish we could use WPF... I think WPF is the best-in-breed for that domain.)

@Eljay i removed that, it has min and max, apperantly they only do it once per measure but iteratively, so they don't run into the exponential complexity issue but it can fail to calculate the layout for very complex systems ...
